# Find the equation of the normal to the curve $y = 8/(4 + x^2)$ , at $x = 1$.

Tags: calculus

When you first differentiate the above, you get $-8/25$, right? Then you derive the gradient for a normal and proceed so on and so forth.
The textbook I'm using says when you differentiate, you get $-16/25$. I believe that's wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f(x)=8(4+x^2)^{-1}$; then
$$
f'(x)=8\cdot(-1)\cdot(4+x^2)^{-2}\cdot 2x
$$
by the chain rule.

Then $f'(4)=-64\cdot20^{-2}=-\dfrac{16}{25}$, so the slope of the normal is $\dfrac{25}{16}$. Since $f(4)=\dfrac{2}{5}$, the normal is
$$
y-\frac{2}{5}=\frac{25}{16}(x-4)
$$

Answer (score 2):

The textbook is correct.

You can use
$$\left\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right\}^\prime=\frac{f^\prime(x)g(x)-f(x)g^\prime(x)}{\{g(x)\}^2}.$$

Letting $$h(x)=\frac{8}{4+x^2},$$
we have 
$$h^\prime(x)=\frac{0-8\cdot 2x}{(4+x^2)^2}=-\frac{16x}{(4+x^2)^2}.$$

Hence, we will have 
$$h(1)=-\frac{16}{25}.$$

So...

Comment: Did you use the product rule and the chain rule? I'm new to calculus.

Comment: The quotient rule was used.

Comment: Also, how do you get to using mathematical notation?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A bit simpler: $\left\{\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\right\}' = \dfrac{-g'(x)}{\left\{g(x)\right\}^2}$. Sometimes it's worth knowing  that special case of the quotient rule. ${}\qquad{}$